# How to add a spacing whose size is of a combobox in Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I need to align the two QLineEdit without adding the first QCheckBox (i.e. a). `QCheckBox.setVisible(False)` won't take up any space. I'm considering to use QHboxLayout.addSpacing(int). But how could I get the size of a QCheckbox?

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QCheckBox,
            QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox)
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        hboxa = QHBoxLayout()
        a = QCheckBox()
        aa = QLineEdit()
        hboxa.addWidget(a)
        hboxa.addWidget(aa)
        gboxa = QGroupBox()
        gboxa.setLayout(hboxa)

        hboxb = QHBoxLayout()
        b = QCheckBox()
        bb = QLineEdit()
        hboxb.addWidget(b)
        hboxb.addWidget(bb)
        gboxb = QGroupBox()
        gboxb.setLayout(hboxb)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(gboxa)
        vbox.addLayout(gboxb)
        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.setWindowTitle('Window Title')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the `sizePolicy`, it controls how the widget is treated by the layout engine when it is re-sized

quoting the docs

The QSizePolicy class is a layout attribute describing horizontal and vertical resizing policy.

> The size policy of a widget is an expression of its willingness to be
>   resized in various ways, and affects how the widget is treated by the
>   layout engine. Each widget returns a QSizePolicy that describes the
>   horizontal and vertical resizing policy it prefers when being laid
>   out. You can change this for a specific widget by changing its
>   QWidget.sizePolicy property.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QCheckBox,
            QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout)
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        hboxa = QHBoxLayout()
        a = QCheckBox()
        # size policy
        not_resize = a.sizePolicy();
        not_resize.setRetainSizeWhenHidden(True);
        a.setSizePolicy(not_resize);
        a.setVisible(False)

        aa = QLineEdit()
        hboxa.addWidget(a)
        hboxa.addWidget(aa)
        hboxb = QHBoxLayout()
        b = QCheckBox()
        bb = QLineEdit()
        hboxb.addWidget(b)
        hboxb.addWidget(bb)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(hboxa)
        vbox.addLayout(hboxb)
        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.setWindowTitle('Window Title')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

More info and docs http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsizepolicy.html

Comment: I modified my question to restrict the condition a little more. Just keep you informed. Your solution still works.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`QGridLayout`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgridlayout.html) instead.  You can remove or hide either one of the checkboxes and it should still maintain the alignment.

```
a = QCheckBox()
aa = QLineEdit()
b = QCheckBox()
bb = QLineEdit()

lay = QGridLayout()
lay.addWidget(a, 0, 0)
lay.addWidget(aa, 0, 1)
lay.addWidget(b, 1, 0)
lay.addWidget(bb, 1, 1)
lay.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
w = QWidget()
w.setLayout(lay)
```

Comment: The QCheckBoxs and QLineEdits are actually within QGroupBoxs. I'm sorry I simplied my codes too much. I already modified my question.